# Average n 2D clusters into one finale result

Tags: clustering

I have n clusters run on 3D data, resulting n 2D clusters, I couldn't run the clustering model on a one year satellite mages time-serie. So I did chunks of one month and run clustering which finally gave: 12 sets of 2D clusters like:

```
Set 1:
lat, lon, class
10, 10, 1
10, 20, 2
20, 10, 3
...

Set 2:
lat, lon, class
10, 10, 2
10, 20, 2
20, 10, 3
...

...
```

I would like an approximate for what it would be to run the clustering model on 365 data, in other words the best average of the clusters. Even if it does not take into consideration the time order between these clusters. It would be less correct for a clustering on all data but still fair.

Comment: Interesting problem, and I like your approach. At the moment I do not see any problem doing so. But what is the actual question? And out of curiosity, what kind of clustering you use for spatial data? DBSCAN?

Comment: I know about `DBSCAN`, but I am using `GeoPAT2` package, which is more suitable for geospacial patterns, also the tool `gpat_gridts` is able of capturing time dimension, so a clustering while capturing transitions, for some reason, it does not scale well for many layers as more than 50. But I should try anyway, also, inputs must have the same environment variables which are a lot in case of raster files (origin, extent variables ...) So a lot of cleansing is needed to normalize also to impute NODATA. I do not know a lot about geo-things, still trying.

Comment: sorry I forgot, the question is how to get from say two clustering results, an approximate clustering scene, even using k-means;

Comment: Why not cluster all the data? if scale is an issue, sample it down or use a tool that can scale up. This shouldn't be challenging even at extreme scale. Clustering that works well for one subset may not work well for the whole one, and there is no easy way to decide which cluster maps to which other cluster in a second clusteirng.